# How does plate thickness affect magnetic levitation?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, ferromagnetism

I’ve been watching videos: [Like this](https://youtu.be/sENgdSF8ppA?si=1zdXU62owvJstle-) about magnetic levitation. They have a copper plate, normally quite thick, a smaller disk magnet under, and a larger disk magnet on top. Upon movement of the smaller magnet, eddy currents are induced and so the top magnet is levitated. How would the thickness of the copper plate affect the levitation?

Comment: Bumping this question…

Comment: Perhaps you can indicate where in yoyr reference exactly this smaller and larger magnet can be seen. It is now a bit unclear.